# Return default value if Query is Empty

Tags: entity-framework, linq, linqpad

I'm creating a linq query in which I need to return minimum and maximum values of the years and prices of cars.

Linqpad:

```
 var result = (from c in Cars           
                 where c.IsShowed == true
                       c.CarCod == carCod                                  
                 group c by c.CarCod into cg
                 select new  {
                 MinPrice = cg.Min(cv => cv.Price) ,
                 MaxPrice = cg.Max(cv => cv.Price),
                 MinYear =  cg.Min(cv => cv.Year),
                 MaxYear =  cg.Max(cv => cv.Year)
                  })
                 .SingleOrDefault();

result.Dump();
```

How would I return a default value, example 0, for all properties MinPrice, MaxPrice, MinYear, MaxYear if the query is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should declare intermediate `Result` class for that:

```
 var result = (from c in Cars           
               where c.IsShowed && c.CarCod == carCod                                  
               group c by c.CarCod into cg
               select new Result {
                   MinPrice = cg.Min(cv => cv.Price) ,
                   MaxPrice = cg.Max(cv => cv.Price),
                   MinYear =  cg.Min(cv => cv.Year),
                   MaxYear =  cg.Max(cv => cv.Year)
               })
               .SingleOrDefault() ?? new Result();
```